# Error thrown Call to undefined function simple_fields_get_post_group_values()

Tags: fatal-error

https://marthawilliamson.com/video-archives/

https://marthawilliamson.com/remembering-valerie-harper/

I'm trying to access specific parts of the following website, but I keep getting this error message instead.

Error thrown

Call to undefined function simple_fields_get_post_group_values()

Does anyone know why I am getting this, and if this can be fixed? Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: All of the videos in the link give me this message: Error thrown

Call to undefined function simple_fields_get_post_group_values()